# How to get checkbox value in mvc?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

when i will select check box and will be clicked select button how i can get this value to the textbox value. Here checkbox id= chk and textbox id = OrderNo. Please help me ....I have something in below....

```
$("#OrderNo").blur(function() {
    $.get('/Ordering/OrderList/', function(data) {
        $('#orlist').html(data);
    });
    $('#orlist').dialog({
        width: 500,
        height: 350,
        open: true,
        title: 'Select Order',
        buttons: {
            Select: function() {
                if (("#chk") == 'checked') {
                    var por = ("#porderno").val();
                    por = ("#OrderNo");
                }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $('#orlist').dialog('close');
                $('#orlist').empty();
            }
        }
    });
```

Partial view page is

```
@model IEnumerable<testcon.OrderM>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OdrId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderNo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CId)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBox("OdrId", new { @id="chk"})
        </td>
         <td class="left">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderNo, new { @id="porderno"})
        </td>
        <td class="left">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CId)
        </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

And My Create View page is

```
@model testcon.DeliveryInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>DeliveryInfo</legend>

        @*<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DId)
        </div>*@
        <div class="editor-field">
           Delivery Id : @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DId)
        </div>

        @*<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderNo)
        </div>*@
        <div class="editor-field">
          Order No :@Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderNo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderNo)
            @*<a href="#" onclick="javascript:getOrderList()">Show Order</a>*@
        </div>

       @* <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DDate)
        </div>*@
        <div class="editor-field">
           Delivery Date : @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DDate)
        </div>

        @*<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DQuantity)
        </div>*@
        <div class="editor-field">
           Delivery Quantity: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DQuantity)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DQuantity)
        </div>

        @*<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DAmount)
        </div>*@
        <div class="editor-field">
           Delivery Amount : @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DAmount)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DAmount)
        </div>
        <div id="orlist" >
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: can you show your html code

Comment: This ("#chk"), must be $("#chk") and this var por = ("#porderno").val(); should be var por = ("#porderno").val($(("#chk")).val()); Also remove this line por = ("#OrderNo"); i don´t understand why that.

Comment: @akhlesh i have updated my html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.is(':checked')` check if checked...

```
buttons: {
    Select: function() {
        if ($("#chk").is(':checked')) {
            $("#OrderNo").val($("#porderno").val());
        }
    },
```

Comment: boss good to see that your code is working....But the problem is that i want to get porderno value to OrderNo. how i can do this?

Comment: Just updated answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

to check if the check box is checked in `jQuery`, you can do it by either

```
//will return true if the check box is checked otherwise false!
$("#chkBoxId").is(':checked');
```

**or**

this approach is good when dealing with group of radio buttons/checkboxes.

```
//will yield the same result if checkbox is checked
$('input[name="chkBoxName"]:checked').val();
```

So you can use them in your code like what @[Anthony Chu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3199781/anthony-chu) has responded which i was about to write :)